# how to measure page load performance on inertiajs app

Tags: laravel, vue.js, single-page-application, inertiajs

i need to measure page load performance on inertiajs app. since inertiajs is more like SPA, i'm not sure i can do server side render time after index page loaded. i just wondering is there a way to do this in inertiajs app?to measure how long the time between page routes/requests.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

:) I think you might be looking for the out of the box [progress indicator](https://inertiajs.com/progress-indicators). You can add an event listener when a new Inertia visit is initiated.

With that, you can start a timer whenever an event is fired. :)